# React native with expo. images are loading slowly. need your advice. how to quickly display images?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-fast-image

first time writing on react native. The problem is that the images load slowly even though the image size is very small. I tried the react native fast image library, but I think it doesn't fit with expo,  I don't have an ios folder in my expo to download POD.

When i changed Image component to FastImage it gives an error "FastImageView was not found in the UIManager. Will it work in production when I upload applications to the app store? or do you know other libraries that are compatible with expo to load image fast ? (expo fast image doesnt work)